# How to invert $ \binom{9}{x} \binom{x}{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor} = \sum_{k=0}^{3} f(x,k) \: 2^k $ in relation to Tic-Tac-Toe?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

"Tic-Tac-Toe" is a game played on a 3x3 grid where 2 players alternate taking turns placing tokens (X's and O's) onto the grid. The game is completed when one player has reached 3 of their same tokens in a row. (Note: a "play" in this case is used in the chess sense that a single person has placed a piece.)

For the time being, I ignored cases where a "win" would stop the game to simply get the legal boards for each play. After I figure out $f(x,k)$ below, I will then subtract those out.

It is immediately clear that there are $9!$ total positions but this ignores legality, rotation, and reflection. Also, it is apparent that the symmetry of the board is the dihedral group of order 8.
Using this information and a simple python script gives:

$$
\begin{array}{|| c | c  c  c c | c |c ||}
 \hline
  & {Orbits} & & & \\
 \hline
 Plays & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & Unique & Total  \\
 \hline
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 9 \\
 \hline
 2 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 12 & 72 \\
 \hline
 3 & 0 & 2 & 10 & 26 & 38 & 252 \\
 \hline
 4 & 0 & 2 & 24 & 82 & 108 & 756 \\
 \hline
 5 & 0 & 2 & 30 & 142 & 174 & 1260 \\
 \hline
 6 & 0 & 0 & 36 & 192 & 228 & 1680 \\
 \hline
 7 & 0 & 2 & 30 & 142 & 174 & 1260 \\
 \hline
 8 & 2 & 0 & 17 & 70 & 89 & 630 \\
 \hline
 9 & 2 & 0 & 11 & 10 & 23 & 126 \\
 \hline
\end{array}
$$
For example, the fourth play has 108 unique boards which can be broken down to 2 unique boards that have an orbit of 2 (4 boards total), 24 unique boards that have an orbit of 4 (so 96 boards total) and then 82 unique boards that have an orbit of 8 (656 boards total) which gives a grand total of 756 total boards.

Realizing that the total "legal" boards for each play $x$ is $ \binom{9}{x} \binom{x}{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor} $, the function $f(x,k)$ would then represent the number of unique boards that have an orbit of $2^k$ for each play $x$ as shown below.

$$ \binom{9}{x} \binom{x}{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor} = \sum_{k=0}^{3} f(x,k) \: 2^k $$

So my question is: How do I invert that sum to solve for $f(x,k)$?

Comment: I may miss something, but it seems that you’re missing constraints here as for each giving $x$, you have four unknowns. Namely $f(0,x), \dots, f(3,x)$.

Comment: $f(x,0)$ is the first column in the table so $f(3,0)=0$ (number of $2^0$ orbits in the third play) and $f(8,0)=2$ (number of $2^0$ orbits in the eighth play). Also, $f(x,2)$ is the third column in the table so $f(6,2)=36$. I could be way off base, but wouldn't that table be enough constraints to give a viable solution? Sorry the original comment had an error.